# DRY in ROR routes description

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, nested-resources, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have nested combination of routes in json rest application used for different dropdown lists and grouping

```
 resources :cities, :only =>[:index,:show] 
 resources :regions, :only =>[:index,:show] do
     resources :cities, :only=>[:index, :show] 
 end    
 resources :countries, :only=>[:index,:show] do
   resources :cities, :only=>[:index,:show] 
   resources :regions, :only=>[:index,:show] 
 end
```

Is there a way to describe it more DRY-way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually need these routes I think you can't do very much about it. Probably you can just write it in a more concise way using [with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options):

```
  with_options :only => [:index, :show] do |w|

    w.resources :cities
    w.resources :regions do
      w.resources :cities
    end

    w.resources :countries do
      w.resources :cities
      w.resources :regions
    end

  end
```